# How to prevent SetWindowPos() from making the window fullscreen?

Tags: c, winapi

When I pass the dimentions of my screen and the `(0, 0)` position to the `SetWindowPos()` or `MooveWindow()` functions, they work but they make my window ( it has the `WS_POPUP` and `WS_EX_LAYERED` flags ) behave differently : normally, if a window has an area that overlaps with the taskbar, the taskbar will be rendered on top of the window, but in this case, the window completly hides the taskbar. And the colour key doesn't works correclty. Those behaviours are reminiscent of a full screen window. My problem is that I want my program to be able to make a windonw cover all the pixels of a monitor that doesn't have any taskbar but to keep the ability to use the colour key, which is not possible because calling the function like this will make the window full screen which breaks the colour key. So I would like to know how to prevent `SetWindowPos()` from making the window full screen, even if I pass the dimentions of the screen, for exemple with a flag or using another function.

EDIT : And if there is no solution (a window with the dimentions of the screen has to to be full screen) please tell me.

How I create the window :

```
WindowClass.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
WindowClass.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
WindowClass.lpszClassName = L"WindowsClass";
WindowClass.hbrBackground = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(30, 30, 30));

// ...

HWND Window = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_LAYERED,
    L"WindowsClass", L"FinalWindow", WS_POPUP | WS_MINIMIZEBOX |
    WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, 100, 100, 500, 500, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Window, RGB(30, 30, 30), 0, LWA_COLORKEY);
```

How I use SetWindowPos() :

```
int ScreenWidth = GetDeviceCaps(FinalWindowDeviceContext, HORZRES);
int ScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(FinalWindowDeviceContext, VERTRES);
SetWindowPos(FinalWindow, NULL, 0, 0, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0);
```

Comment: The window needs to be borderless to overlap the taskbar.  Kinda painful to get the border functionality back, but lots of web pages show how to do that.

Comment: This window is borderless.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `NULL` value for `hWndInsertAfter` it is better to set `SWP_NOZORDER` unless you want to put your window on top (of nontopmost windows). `NULL` value means `HWND_TOP`.

```
SetWindowPos(FinalWindow, NULL, x, y, w, h, SWP_NOZORDER);
```

To make window smaller by excluding area covered by taskbar, use `GetMonitorInfo` to obtain `MONOTRINFO`. `rcWork` field contains `RECT` for monitor area not used by any appbar (e.g. taskbar).

```
POINT       point = {0, 0};
HMONITOR    monitor = MonitorFromPoint(point, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
MONITORINFO mi;
mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
GetMonitorInfo(monitor, &mi);
RECT        work_area = mi.rcWork;

SetWindowPos(
    FinalWindow,
    NULL,
    work_area.left,
    work_area.top,
    work_area.right - work_area.left;
    work_area.bottom - work_area.top,
    SWP_NOZORDER); // To prevent z-order change
```

Comment: I don't want to make it smaller and I know how to retrieve tohe work area, this is not what I need, I should have mentioned that. What I want is a window that **has the dimentions of the screen** This is necessary for exemple if I want to maximize a window on a monitor that doesn't have a taskbar.

Comment: _"I want is a window that has the dimentions of the screen"_ - this is what your original code does. Maybe you don't like consequence that making active window with size (ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight) sends `ABN_FULLSCREENAPP` message to taskbar which drops itself to the bottom of the z-order and goes under your window. If you insist on your window going below taskbar use `ScreenHeight-1`. You should also elaborate on _"colour key doesn't works correclty"_ because it seems to work (at least drawing some rectangles on transparent window).